# Generate XML document in R

Tags: r, xml

In the project I am working, I need to automatize the creation of an `XML` document depending on the user input. The part of using the user input to modify the `xml` document is okay for me but I am new in creating `xml` documents from scratch in R

I am wondering if an `XML` document like the one below can be generated in R using the `XML` or `xml2` packages. So far, I have explored the `newXMLdoc`, `xml_new_document` and `xml_new_root` functions but I am not familiar with all the syntax needed to create such an `xml` file (which should be saved in a local path once finished)

```
<session>
  <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
  <products>
    <product>
      <refNo>1</refNo>
      <uri>S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190818T175529_20190818T175554_028627_033D25_22ED.zip</uri>
      <productReaderPlugin>class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn</productReaderPlugin>
    </product>
    <product>
      <refNo>2</refNo>
      <uri>S2A_MSIL1C_20190823T061631_N0208_R034_T42TXS_20190823T081730.zip</uri>
      <productReaderPlugin>class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn</productReaderPlugin>
    </product>
  </products>
  <views/>
</session>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easily solveable w/out any of those packages... if your structure is fairly static, I would use https://github.com/tidyverse/glue and then just `cat()` the file out. Something like this:

```
## I guess your data looks like this?
df <- data.frame(number = c(1,2),
                 uri = c("S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190818T175529_20190818T175554_028627_033D25_22ED.zip<",
                         "S2A_MSIL1C_20190823T061631_N0208_R034_T42TXS_20190823T081730.zip"),
                 plugin = c("class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn",
                            "class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn"))
df

## build a function that outputs every block in xml format
thingieBuilder <- function(number, uri, plugin){
  glue::glue("<product>
           <refNo>{number}</refNo>
           <uri>{uri}</uri>
           <productReaderPlugin>{plugin}</productReaderPlugin>
           </product>")
}

## now run that for each entry in your df and unlist it, and make it a sausage, seperated by newlines
xmlProducts <- df %>% purrr::pmap(thingieBuilder) %>% unlist %>% paste(collapse = "\n")

## Now stick on top and bottom, and cat it to a file!
glue::glue("<session>
  <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
  <products>\n",
           xmlProducts,
           "/n</products>
             <views/>
           </session>") %>% 
  cat(file = "boom.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks! I an having issues to find the `pmap` function. Could you please list the packages used. `glue` + ...?

Comment: XML is not quite a text file. OP's aforementioned methods can build XML with DOM methods.

Comment: sorry... pmap is in the purrr package. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Consider building XML with DOM methods using aforementioned libraries such as `XML` without the need of concatenating or interpolating strings:

```
library(XML)

# DATA
df <- data.frame(refNo = c(1, 2),
                 uri = c('S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190818T175529_20190818T175554_028627_033D25_22ED.zip', 
                         'S2A_MSIL1C_20190823T061631_N0208_R034_T42TXS_20190823T081730.zip'),
                 plugin = c('class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn', 
                            'class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn')
                )

# CREATE XML FILE
doc = newXMLDoc()
root = newXMLNode("session", doc = doc)

# WRITE XML NODES AND DATA
mvNode = newXMLNode("modelVersion", "1.0.0", parent = root)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  prodNode = newXMLNode("products", parent = root)

  # APPEND TO PRODUCT NODE
  newXMLNode("refNo", df$refNo[i], parent = prodNode)
  newXMLNode("uri", df$uri[i], parent = prodNode)
  newXMLNode("productReaderPlugin", df$plugin[i], parent = prodNode)
}

vwNode = newXMLNode("views", parent = root)

# OUTPUT XML CONTENT TO CONSOLE
print(doc)

# OUTPUT XML CONTENT TO FILE
saveXML(doc, file="Output.xml")
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<session>
  <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
  <products>
    <refNo>1</refNo>
    <uri>S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190818T175529_20190818T175554_028627_033D25_22ED.zip</uri>
    <productReaderPlugin>class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn</productReaderPlugin>
  </products>
  <products>
    <refNo>2</refNo>
    <uri>S2A_MSIL1C_20190823T061631_N0208_R034_T42TXS_20190823T081730.zip</uri>
    <productReaderPlugin>class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn</productReaderPlugin>
  </products>
  <views/>
</session>
```

Answer (score 7):

Package **xml2** [(cran)](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=xml2) provides an alternative solution within the Hadleyuniverse.

```r
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(number = c(1, 2),
  uri = c('S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190818T175529_20190818T175554_028627_033D25_22ED.zip', 
    'S2A_MSIL1C_20190823T061631_N0208_R034_T42TXS_20190823T081730.zip'),
  plugin = c('class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn', 
    'class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We first create the xml doc that will contain all xml structure

```r
doc <- xml_new_root("session") 
xml_add_child(doc, "modelVersion", "1.0.0")  
xml_add_child(doc, "products") 
xml_add_child(doc, "products") 
xml_add_child(doc, "views")
doc
#> {xml_document}
#> <session>
#> [1] <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
#> [2] <products/>
#> [3] <products/>
#> [4] <views/>
```

We add now the components in each product node.
No loop is required as `xml_add_child` function is vectorized.

```r
products_nodes <- xml_find_all(doc, "//products")
xml_add_child(products_nodes, "refNo", df$number)
xml_add_child(products_nodes, "uri", df$uri)
xml_add_child(products_nodes, "productReaderPlugin", df$plugin)
```

Save finally the xml tree into a file and show the content of it

```r
write_xml(doc, file = "output.xml", options =c("format", "no_declaration"))
cat(paste0(readLines("output.xml"), collapse = "\n"))
```

This is the content of "output.xml" file:

```xml
<session>
  <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
  <products>
    <refNo>1</refNo>
    <uri>S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190818T175529_20190818T175554_028627_033D25_22ED.zip</uri>
    <productReaderPlugin>class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn</productReaderPlugin>
  </products>
  <products>
    <refNo>2</refNo>
    <uri>S2A_MSIL1C_20190823T061631_N0208_R034_T42TXS_20190823T081730.zip</uri>
    <productReaderPlugin>class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn</productReaderPlugin>
  </products>
  <views/>
</session>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This migth be a better alternative considering what is stated here: https://gist.github.com/nuest/3ed3b0057713eb4f4d75d11bb62f2d66